# facebook graph search type=post how to get post's comments

Tags: facebook

In facebook graph search, type=post

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&token=XXXXXXXXX`

It return data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "100001477475394_211188005607114",
         "from": {
            "name": "Jerry Garcia",
            "id": "100001477475394"
         },
         "message": "I like watermelon,fried chicken and koolaid !\nWhat does that make me ? lol",
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-09-07T21:33:28+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-09-07T21:33:58+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Natalie Hurtado",
                  "id": "100002486021428"
               }
            ],
            "count": 1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So how to get this post's comment? (fql also welcome)

and what is the `{data->id}` (100001477475394_211188005607114), I tried `fql.steam query` nothing return, so it is not a `post_id`. how can I get this post id?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing a request on `211188005607114`? The first part (before the underscore) is the id of the poster, so maybe the second part correspond to something else, and this 'id' is some kind of association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add &fields=comments(,other fields)
or make another call to the graph using id/comments 
for detail see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ 
look for comments

Comment: many thanks, this is what I need, still one question about the `post id`. after I use `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&fields=from,message,comments,description,id&token=XXXXXX` return the data. the id which doc said is a post id, but i put them into `https://graph.facebook.com/100001477475394_211188005607114&access_token=XXXXXX` get the data back `false`. I followed `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/` top example. Thanks again.